# Binary Serialization

Tags: .net, serialization

Suppose I have option in my application to load project files (in fact it's deserialization of .bin file). How can I prevent my application from running user-modifed files? I'd also know is it possible to merge 2 .bin files? For instance can I merge "History" class serialized object (history.bin) and "Document" class serialized object (document.bin) into one file for example "project.bin"? I'd like to deserialize these two objects using just one file. Are there any build-in methods for compression in .NET?

Comment: [System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) for serialization and [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) for compression.

Comment: You mean _merge_ into one file rather than _split_?

Comment: And to avoid user manipulation, encrypt them.